# Undefined method setText() when chaining findViewById() for TextView

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if anyone could tell me why:

```
TextView textblock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label).setText("Google is your friend.", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

I get an undefined method error (setText is undefined for this type of view). However works when I do not chain e.g:

```
TextView textblock = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
textblock.setText("Google is your friend.", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

(I know this is a very basic question, however I am new to Java and could not find anything in my searches)

Comment: `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.label)).setText("...");` First cast to TextView and then set Text, have a look at my brackets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the method on the casted result, thanks to additional parentheses:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.label)).setText("Google is your friend.", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

That said, introducing a variable makes the code more readable. I would do that instead.

Also note that `setText()` returns void, and not the TextView. So you can't initialize a TextView variable with the result of `setText()` like you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`setText()` is of type `void` thus it doesnt return anything, which means you cant store in variable.